# Python 3.9.9 Error " 'module' object is not a callable' - I am trying to download and extract .tgz file

Tags: python

I am trying to download and extract some data in .tgz file which I need to proceed with my book.
But unfortunately the code does not work.
I am receiving this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:...\Python39_SciKit_&_TF_chapter2\main.py", 
line 67, in <module>
fetch_housing_data()
File "C:...\Python39_SciKit_&_TF_chapter2\main.py", 
line 54, in fetch_housing_data
with tarfile(FILE) as tar_data:
TypeError: 'module' object is not callable
```

And the code is:

```
# fetching data
URL = 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ageron/handson-ml2/master/datasets/housing/housing.tgz'
FILE = 'housing.tgz'
FOLDER = 'datasets'
def fetch_housing_data():
if not os.path.isfile(FILE):
    print(f'Downloading {URL} and saving as {FILE}...')
    urllib.request.urlretrieve(URL, FILE)
    print('Unpacking file...')
    with tarfile(FILE) as tar_data:
        tar_data.extractall(FOLDER)

    print('Tgz data has been extracted')
else:
    print('The file is already in the folder')
```

And I don't know why this line gives an error:`

```
with tarfile(FILE) as tar_data:
        tar_data.extractall(FOLDER)
```

Since I was using very similar approach with zip files and it worked.
Why python recognizes this as not collable and how do I make it work?

Comment: Please post a fully self-contained [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that can be run as-is to reproduce the problem. (In particular, I suspect your error has to do with an incorrect `import`, but it's impossible to say for sure at this point.) Also please verify that your indentation displays properly.

Comment: Where did you get `with tarfile(FILE) as tar_data` from? Is that supposed to be `with tarfile.open(FILE) as tar_data`?

Comment: @Brian YES!
Thank you this was it! Tbh I can say I am quite new in python regarding various packages, so sometimes I may don't know what I did wrong.

Thank you once again!

Comment: When in doubt, read the documentation https://docs.python.org/3/library/tarfile.html#examples